# What is the best way to write Django for user interaction using button which updates values in the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, relational-database

I am trying to write Django code for below:

A user presses a button in the frontend. Multiple button options to decrement value by 10, 20, 30 etc.

When the user presses the button, value for a Django model attribute in the backend will decrement accordingly. For example in the code below I set the intial value to 107. When the user presses the "Subtract 10" button in the html template, I want 10 subtracted from 107, so that the value then becomes 97. User is not entering any data.

I unsuccessfully tried to use Django modelForm and "POST" and that did not work.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Below is the code I had that did not work.

models.py

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    userBalance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class BalanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Balance
        fields = ['userBalance']
```

views.py

```
def balance(request):
    form = BalanceForm(initial={"userBalance":107})
    if form.is_valid():
        if request.method == "POST" and "form10" in request.POST:
            formValue = form.cleaned_data.get('userBalance')
            form2 = formValue - 10
            return render(request, "econlabs/balance.html", {'form2': form2})
    return render(request, "econlabs/balance.html", {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an updateview for that Model and specify the fields that you would like to update. You can use a custom form, But trust me these generic views will save you a lot of time .

views.py :

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView


class updBalanceUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Balance
    fields = ['userBalance']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

Of all the attributes, you can mention the ones you need to be updated.
As shown in the last line above (template_name_suffix) , use the same naming suffix pattern for the template... [modelname_update_form.html] and display the form...

**Balance_update_form.html :**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap_tags %}
{% block title %} Update {% endblock %}

{% block body%}
<div class="jumbotron">
    Are you sure you want to update ?
</div>
<br>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|as_bootstrap  }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

make sure you get the corresponding element you want to update from the template :

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'app_name:update' pk=val.pk %}">update</a></h3>
```

clicking the above triggers the url. Add the urls ,

**urls.py:**

```
path('update/<int:pk>', views.updBalanceUpdateView.as_view() , name = "update"),
```

PS: You can also update values from views using queries to select the desired object and then editing them like this ,

**in views.py :**

```
example = Balance.objects.filter(id = pk).update(userBalance = userBalance - 10)
```

check  out the documentation for more info :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/